# открыть только один блок с текстом при нажатии, но что-бы в остальных была одна и та же высота

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

У меня открываеться один блок но остальные блоки стают в такую ширину какая у них и должна быть хотя текст на остальных не видно. И еще, что самое интересное, если уменьшить экран до 500px , блоки выстроятся в ряд и уже при открытии одного, другие не будут разтягиваться на ту же ширину как в ситуции с компютерной версией. 
Задача: при открытии одного блока что-бы другие не разтягивались на такую же высоту, и если можно объяснение почему так?
Заранее спасибо!

```js
$('.click').each(function () {
 $(this).click(function () {
  $(this).next('.sub_inner').slideToggle(200);
 })
})
```

```css
.wrapp{
   max-width:960px;
   width:100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: -moz-flex;
   display: -ms-flex;
   display: -o-flex;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .inner_wrapp{
   width: 172px;
   margin: 0 10px;
   padding: 5px;
   background: lightpink;
  }
  .click{
   background: #000;
   border:20px solid #fff;
   cursor: pointer;
   width:30px;
   height:30px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   border-radius: 50%;
  }
  .click:hover{
   background: #fff;
   border:20px solid #000;
  }
  .sub_inner{
   display: none;
   margin-top: 15px;
   text-align: right;
   background: #ffffd9;
   padding: 10px 3px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: lightgrey;
   font-style: italic;
  }
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px){
   .wrapp{
    flex-direction: column;
   }
   .inner_wrapp{
    width: auto;
   }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapp">
  <div class="inner_wrapp">
   <div class="click"></div>
   <div class="sub_inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos aliquam nostrum soluta recusandae dicta voluptatibus adipisci rerum doloribus, quidem inventore, incidunt tenetur neque error atque. Aliquid deserunt suscipit omnis beatae autem, quos praesentium consectetur soluta illo sunt vel quaerat a repellat dolore commodi voluptatibus error ratione itaque tenetur culpa laudantium animi dolor, rem perferendis. Ipsa in, cumque, sapiente aspernatur, minima et consequatur libero, eos sunt nostrum enim. Dignissimos libero, expedita!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner_wrapp">
   <div class="click"></div>
   <div class="sub_inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos aliquam nostrum soluta recusandae dicta voluptatibus adipisci rerum doloribus, quidem inventore, incidunt tenetur neque error atque. Aliquid deserunt suscipit omnis beatae autem, quos praesentium consectetur soluta illo sunt vel quaerat a repellat dolore commodi voluptatibus error ratione itaque tenetur culpa laudantium animi dolor, rem perferendis. Ipsa in, cumque, sapiente aspernatur, minima et consequatur libero, eos sunt nostrum enim. Dignissimos libero, expedita!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner_wrapp">
   <div class="click"></div>
   <div class="sub_inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos aliquam nostrum soluta recusandae dicta voluptatibus adipisci rerum doloribus, quidem inventore, incidunt tenetur neque error atque. Aliquid deserunt suscipit omnis beatae autem, quos praesentium consectetur soluta illo sunt vel quaerat a repellat dolore commodi voluptatibus error ratione itaque tenetur culpa laudantium animi dolor, rem perferendis. Ipsa in, cumque, sapiente aspernatur, minima et consequatur libero, eos sunt nostrum enim. Dignissimos libero, expedita!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner_wrapp">
   <div class="click"></div>
   <div class="sub_inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos aliquam nostrum soluta recusandae dicta voluptatibus adipisci rerum doloribus, quidem inventore, incidunt tenetur neque error atque. Aliquid deserunt suscipit omnis beatae autem, quos praesentium consectetur soluta illo sunt vel quaerat a repellat dolore commodi voluptatibus error ratione itaque tenetur culpa laudantium animi dolor, rem perferendis. Ipsa in, cumque, sapiente aspernatur, minima et consequatur libero, eos sunt nostrum enim. Dignissimos libero, expedita!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner_wrapp">
   <div class="click"></div>
   <div class="sub_inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos aliquam nostrum soluta recusandae dicta voluptatibus adipisci rerum doloribus, quidem inventore, incidunt tenetur neque error atque. Aliquid deserunt suscipit omnis beatae autem, quos praesentium consectetur soluta illo sunt vel quaerat a repellat dolore commodi voluptatibus error ratione itaque tenetur culpa laudantium animi dolor, rem perferendis. Ipsa in, cumque, sapiente aspernatur, minima et consequatur libero, eos sunt nostrum enim. Dignissimos libero, expedita!</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Ширину или высоту?

Comment: высоту, опечатка извините

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо поставить свойсто `align-items: start` для `.wrapp`, потому что по умолчанию стоит `stretch`.

```js
$('.click').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    $(this).next('.sub_inner').slideToggle(200);
  })
})
```

```css
.wrapp {
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: start; // Установить значение
}

.inner_wrapp {
  width: 172px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: lightpink;
}

.click {
  background: #000;
  border: 20px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.click:hover {
  background: #fff;
  border: 20px solid #000;
}

.sub_inner {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  background: #ffffd9;
  padding: 10px 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: lightgrey;
  font-style: italic;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .wrapp {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .inner_wrapp {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapp">
  <div class="inner_wrapp">
    <div class="click"></div>
    <div class="sub_inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos aliquam nostrum soluta recusandae dicta voluptatibus adipisci rerum doloribus, quidem inventore, incidunt tenetur neque error atque. Aliquid deserunt suscipit omnis beatae autem, quos praesentium
      consectetur soluta illo sunt vel quaerat a repellat dolore commodi voluptatibus error ratione itaque tenetur culpa laudantium animi dolor, rem perferendis. Ipsa in, cumque, sapiente aspernatur, minima et consequatur libero, eos sunt nostrum enim.
      Dignissimos libero, expedita!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner_wrapp">
    <div class="click"></div>
    <div class="sub_inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos aliquam nostrum soluta recusandae dicta voluptatibus adipisci rerum doloribus, quidem inventore, incidunt tenetur neque error atque. Aliquid deserunt suscipit omnis beatae autem, quos praesentium
      consectetur soluta illo sunt vel quaerat a repellat dolore commodi voluptatibus error ratione itaque tenetur culpa laudantium animi dolor, rem perferendis. Ipsa in, cumque, sapiente aspernatur, minima et consequatur libero, eos sunt nostrum enim.
      Dignissimos libero, expedita!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner_wrapp">
    <div class="click"></div>
    <div class="sub_inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos aliquam nostrum soluta recusandae dicta voluptatibus adipisci rerum doloribus, quidem inventore, incidunt tenetur neque error atque. Aliquid deserunt suscipit omnis beatae autem, quos praesentium
      consectetur soluta illo sunt vel quaerat a repellat dolore commodi voluptatibus error ratione itaque tenetur culpa laudantium animi dolor, rem perferendis. Ipsa in, cumque, sapiente aspernatur, minima et consequatur libero, eos sunt nostrum enim.
      Dignissimos libero, expedita!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner_wrapp">
    <div class="click"></div>
    <div class="sub_inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos aliquam nostrum soluta recusandae dicta voluptatibus adipisci rerum doloribus, quidem inventore, incidunt tenetur neque error atque. Aliquid deserunt suscipit omnis beatae autem, quos praesentium
      consectetur soluta illo sunt vel quaerat a repellat dolore commodi voluptatibus error ratione itaque tenetur culpa laudantium animi dolor, rem perferendis. Ipsa in, cumque, sapiente aspernatur, minima et consequatur libero, eos sunt nostrum enim.
      Dignissimos libero, expedita!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner_wrapp">
    <div class="click"></div>
    <div class="sub_inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos aliquam nostrum soluta recusandae dicta voluptatibus adipisci rerum doloribus, quidem inventore, incidunt tenetur neque error atque. Aliquid deserunt suscipit omnis beatae autem, quos praesentium
      consectetur soluta illo sunt vel quaerat a repellat dolore commodi voluptatibus error ratione itaque tenetur culpa laudantium animi dolor, rem perferendis. Ipsa in, cumque, sapiente aspernatur, minima et consequatur libero, eos sunt nostrum enim.
      Dignissimos libero, expedita!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да спасибо, вроде очень простое задание, но забыл про этот stretch - это же и есть разтягивание))